# Writing data incrementally using To File block in Simulink

Tags: logging, simulink

I am looking to output results from Simulink to a .mat file after every time step (or every few time steps). The To File block looks like the best way to do this, according to the documentation. However, I have tried using To File blocks and the results do not appear to be saved to the .mat file until the simulation is stopped. How can I log results incrementally in Simulink?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It's very inefficient, and there's a good chance that there are better ways of achieving what you are thinking of doing this for.

Comment: I have often had issues where, after running a Simulink simulation overnight, I come back and MATLAB has crashed. When this happens I lose all of the results I was writing to the workspace. If the results are written to an actual file incrementally, even if MATLAB crashes I still retain the results from the simulation completed up until then.

Comment: The data is written to the workspace or file only when the simulation is stopped. I suggest you try to address the issue of why MATLAB has crashed instead. By the sound of it, it seems like a memory issue. Either run your model for less time, log less data, increase your step size and/or sample time, get more memory, etc... There are various resources available on the MathWorks website on managing memory in MATLAB and Simulink.